# Map list elements to keys in dictionary for decimal values in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of words as below.

```
mylist = ['cat', 'yellow', 'car', 'red', 'green', 'jeep', 'rat','lorry']
```

I also have a list of lists for each essay in the dataset that contain values for the 'mylist' as given in the examples below (i.e, if 'mylist' word appears in essay it produces a value between 0-1).

```
[[0,0.7,0,0,0,0.3,0,0.6], [0.2,0,0,0,0,0,0.8,0]]
```

In other words,

```
[0,0.7,0,0,0,0.3,0,0.6] says that this only has values 'yellow', 'jeep', 'lorry'
```

Now I have a dictionary of categories as below.

```
mydictionary = {'colour': ['red', 'yellow', 'green'], 'animal': ['rat','cat'], 
'vehicle': ['car', 'jeep']}
```

Now by using 'mydictionary' key values I want to transform the list of lists as follows (That is, if one or more values of the 'mylist' is 1, I mark the key as the **average** values of the scores).

```
[[0.7, 0, 0.45], [0, 0.5, 0]]
```

In other words,

```
[0.7, 0, 0.45] says that;
0.7 - average value for elements in 'colours' = 0.7/1 = 0.7
0 - no elements in 'animals'
0.45 - average value for elements in 'vehicles' = (0.3+0.6)/2 = 0.45
```

So my output should be a list of lists as mentioned above -> [[0.7, 0, 0.45], [0, 0.5, 0]]

I am interested in knowing if this is possible to do using pandas dataframes.

Comment: Just to note you seem to be asking the same question albeit with slightly different tweaks recently. If this is a learning exercise then it might well be worth your while trying things first and showing what you've tried that didn't work so the community can help you fix the code - rather than crowd source code for each step you get stuck on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really reconsider your data-structures. One problem you will face is that `dict`'s are inherently unordered. So first, enfore the order by putting the values in an ordered container (a `list` works fine):

```
>>> vals = [mydictionary['colour'], mydictionary['animal'], mydictionary['vehicle']]
```

Now the essays:

```
>>> essays = [[0,0.7,0,0,0,0.3,0,0.6], [0.2,0,0,0,0,0,0.8,0]]
```

Then, a simple loop, building a map from `mylist` to each essay weights, and using the `statistics` package for a `mean` function:

```
>>> import statistics as stats
>>> result = []
>>> for essay in essays:
...     map = dict(zip(mylist, essay))
...     result.append([stats.mean(map[e] for e in v) for v in vals])
...
>>> result
[[0.2333333333333333, 0, 0.15], [0, 0.5, 0]]
```

Honestly, Not sure if `pandas` is the best tool for this, but I suppose you could use a `DataFrame` like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'essay{}'.format(i):essay for i, essay in enumerate(essays)}, index=mylist)
>>> df
        essay0  essay1
cat        0.0     0.2
yellow     0.7     0.0
car        0.0     0.0
red        0.0     0.0
green      0.0     0.0
jeep       0.3     0.0
rat        0.0     0.8
lorry      0.6     0.0
```

Then, make a grouper-mapping:

```
>>> grouper  = {v: k for k, vv in mydictionary.items() for v in vv}
```

Then use `pd.DataFrame.groupby`:

```
>>> df.groupby(grouper).mean()
           essay0  essay1
animal   0.000000     0.5
colour   0.233333     0.0
vehicle  0.150000     0.0
```

#### Edit

After the comment, the fix is quite simple, you just materialize the weights into a list, filter for 0 like so: `[map[e] for e in v if map[e]]`, and then take the `mean` of that list. However, you have to take care that the list is not empty. Simply define a helper function that checks or returns a default of 0:

```
>>> def mean_default(seq):
...     if seq:
...         return stats.mean(seq)
...     else:
...         return 0
...
```

Then simply:

```
>>> result = []
>>> for essay in essays:
...     map = dict(zip(mylist, essay))
...     result.append([mean_default([map[e] for e in v if map[e]]) for  in vals])
```

For `pandas`, as @IanS showed, simply replace `0` with `np.nan`.

Comment: Brilliant, I borrowed the `groupby` idea from you (-:

Comment: Didn't know about grouper mapping, you learn something every day!

Comment: @IanS yep, I actually didn't know about it, but I had a hunch that the `groupby` argument could be a mapping, since oftentimes these sorts of things in `pandas` can be a `mapping`, note, that means it could be a `Series` as well!

Comment: Thanks, But the results are bit different.  For example [0,0.7,0,0,0.3,0,0,0.6] -> yellow (0.7) jeep (0.3) and lorry (0.6). Since both jeep and lorry comes under vehicle category I should get the output as -> (0.6 +0.3) = 0.45. Since color category only has yellow -> 0.7/1 ->0.7

Answer (score 1):

**First**, invert keys and values in the dictionary:

```
{v: k for k, l in mydictionary.items() for v in l}
```

Returns:

```
{'car': 'vehicle',
 'cat': 'animal',
 'green': 'colour',
 'jeep': 'vehicle',
 'rat': 'animal',
 'red': 'colour',
 'yellow': 'colour'}
```

**Second**, map this to get the category of the words:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(mylist, columns=['word'])
df['category'] = df['word'].map({v: k for k, l in mydictionary.items() for v in l})
```

Output:

```
# note: I have added lorry to the dictionary
     word category
0     cat   animal
1  yellow   colour
2     car  vehicle
3     red   colour
4   green   colour
5    jeep  vehicle
6     rat   animal
7   lorry  vehicle
```

**Third**, map this to your list of lists by concatenating:

```
df = pd.concat([
    df,
    pd.DataFrame([[0,0.7,0,0,0,0.3,0,0.6], [0.2,0,0,0,0,0,0.8,0]]).T
], axis=1)
```

**Fourth**, group by catgegory:

```
df.groupby('category').mean()
```

Output:

```
                 0    1
category               
animal    0.000000  0.5
colour    0.233333  0.0
vehicle   0.300000  0.0
```

---

**Edit**: to ignore 0 values, replace them with NaN.

```
df.replace({0: np.nan}).groupby('category').mean()
```

Output:

```
             0    1
category           
animal     NaN  0.5
colour    0.70  NaN
vehicle   0.45  NaN
```

You can `fillna(0)` at the end if needed.

Comment: @David I've answered your comment, please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

**Setup**

```
mylist = ['cat', 'yellow', 'car', 'red', 'green', 'jeep', 'rat','lorry']
mydictionary = {
    'colour': ['red', 'yellow', 'green'],
    'animal': ['rat','cat'], 
    'vehicle': ['car', 'jeep', 'lorry']
}
a = np.array([[0,0.7,0,0,0,0.3,0,0.6], [0.2,0,0,0,0,0,0.8,0]])
```

---

**Option 1**
*Simple!*

```
mapping = {v: k for k, l in mydictionary.items() for v in l}

pd.DataFrame(a, columns=mylist).rename(columns=mapping).stack() \
    .compress(lambda x: x > 0).groupby(level=[0, 1]).mean().unstack(fill_value=0)

   animal  colour  vehicle
0     0.0     0.7     0.45
1     0.5     0.0     0.00
```

---

**Option 2**
*Difficult to understand solution, but should be fast.*

```
mapping = {v: k for k, l in mydictionary.items() for v in l}
f, u = pd.factorize([mapping[i] for i in mylist])
r = np.arange(a.shape[0]).repeat(a.shape[1])
c = np.tile(f, a.shape[0])
b = c + r * u.size

counts = np.bincount(b, a.ravel() > 0)
sums = np.bincount(b, a.ravel())
means = sums / np.where(counts > 0, counts, 1) * (counts > 0)

pd.DataFrame(means.reshape(-1, u.size), columns=u)

   animal  colour  vehicle
0     0.0     0.7     0.45
1     0.5     0.0     0.00
```

Comment: Very nice, although, shouldn't you just calculate `map = {v: k for k, l in mydictionary.items() for v in l}` outside the list-comprehension? It doesn't really make a difference in such a small example, but that would be wasteful recalculating inside the comprehension each time..

Comment: It only gets calculated once in the comprehension... I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Edited the question. For example [0,0.7,0,0,0.3,0,0,0.6] -> yellow (0.7) jeep (0.3) and lorry (0.6). Since both jeep and lorry comes under vehicle category I should get the output as -> (0.6 +0.3) = 0.45. Since color category only has yellow -> 0.7/1 ->0.7

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga confirmed, timing is the same either way.

Comment: No, I am *certain* it gets recalculated every time in the comprehension. Unfortunately, Python doesn't allow you to set variables inside comprehensions, so you have to calculate things each iteration, even if you really only need to calculate it once. Haskell's list comprehensions let you do that, and so does Scala's for-expressions. I don't think you'd see much of a difference for such a small `dict` anyway

Comment: I'll trust you (-: and change accordingly

Comment: Yeah, the difference I get using `timeit.timeit` is `9.53739629300253` for the dict-comprehesion inside the list comprehesion, and `1.9363041850010632` for pre-calculating the `dict`